# Sort object with array ordering by key name

Tags: javascript

How can I sort an object, which has an array inside. I need to sort by name in javascript.
My object is:

```
(4) [{...},{...},{...},{...}]
 0: {Age: 10, Name: 'John'}
 1: {Age: 25, Name: 'Maria'}
 2: {Age: 23, Name: 'Ana'}
 3: {Age: 27, Name: 'Pedro'}
```

The output should be an object like this:

```
(4) [{...},{...},{...},{...}]
     0: {Age: 23, Name: 'Ana'}
     1: {Age: 10, Name: 'John'}
     2: {Age: 25, Name: 'Maria'}
     3: {Age: 27, Name: 'Pedro'}
```

Comment: Have you read the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort_)? Also, your example is sorting by a value, not a key name as mentioned in the title.

Answer (score 0):

Sort based on the result of `String.prototype.localeCompare` (note that `Array.prototype.sort` also mutates the original array)

```js
const data = [{Age: 10, Name: 'John'},
{Age: 25, Name: 'Maria'},
{Age: 23, Name: 'Ana'},
{Age: 27, Name: 'Pedro'},]

const newData = data.sort((a, b) => a.Name.localeCompare(b.Name));

console.log(newData);
```